# FreeBSD synth – build llvm crashes – force synth to use official package?

Tags: build, freebsd

The scene:

- FreeBSD 11.1
- synth package builder
- pkg repo set quarterly Fetch Build
- Packages set to true

The problem:

I am trying to build vips (a graphics tool) with synth. One of the dependencies of vips is LLVM. For some reason LLVM (llvm40) is not fetched from the officia quarterly repo while other packages with unchanged configs are.

I wouldn't mind having a fresh llvm40 build, but the build of llvm40 always crashes, after it has compiled for about an hour or so.

So being stuck with this problem for a whole day, I would really like to be able to force synth to just use the version from the official repo.

There's no option like that mentioned anywhere, but maybe sommeone has run into similar problems and knows a solution or workaround.

Comment: Have you tried `pkg install vips` ? it should download/install pre-compiled versions so no need to build

Comment: @nbari

As I wrote, I am building with synth i.e. a  custom repository. Thus pkg install from the official repo is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for posting a solution to my problem, but I've got synth to build llvm40 now.

Step 1: Building gcc6 first. Somehow gcc6 is built together with LLVM which takes up tons of swap space.

Step 2: Build llvm40 but **without the debugger**. So run make config and disable llbd

After that no more swap space problems occured.

Answer (score 0):

To compile from source I would recommend using [portmaster](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html)

For example, this are the steps I did in an empty jail to install from the ports [graphics/vips](https://www.freshports.org/graphics/vips/) (default options)

First, install/update the ports:

```
# portsnatp fetch extract
```

Next, install `portmaster`:

```
# cd /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/portmaster
# make install clean
```

In case you already have the ports you may want to update them before installing the package by using?

```
# portsnap fetch update
```

For installing `vips`:

```
# cd /usr/ports
# portmaster graphics/vips
```

It will prompt for many options including the ones related to LLVM but at the end, it should compile the port, for example, this is the version I compiled:

```
root@xxx:/usr/ports # vips --vips-version
libvips 8.4.5-Sat Oct 28 09:19:20 UTC 2017
```

In case later you would like to update all your ports and avoid pressing many times <kbd>Y</kbd> (yes), you could do something like:

```
# yes | portmaster -da
```

This will just install `vips` but will put on your system all the dependencies (`llvm-*` etc), so later probably you could just use your custom patch/port to include your custom dependencies, probably `synth` (I have no idea what exactly it is) but at least hope this helps you to compile successfully `vips`.